# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header error on Angular file upload for files of certain size

Tags: c#, asp.net, angular, asp.net-web-api

I currently am uploading a file to .NET Web API from an Angular front end.

```
uploadFile(file: File, customerId: number) {
  var formData: FormData = new FormData();
  formData.append('file', file, file.name);
  var headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Accept', 'application/json');
  var options = { headers: headers, reportProgress: true };

  const req = new HttpRequest('POST', 'customers/' + customerId + '/fileupload', formData, options)
  return this.http.request(req);
}
```

And the Web API route that receives this post.

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("{customerId}/fileUpload")]
public IHttpActionResult UploadFiles(int customerId)
{
    if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Files.Count > 0) 
    {
        _fileService.UploadFile(customerId, HttpContext.Current.Request.Files[0]);
        return Ok("Files Successfully Uploaded");
    } 
    else 
    {
        return Ok("0 Files Uploaded");
    }
}
```

When I post a file that is 30,000,000 bytes (~30mb) or less, everything works as expected, but for some reason, when the file is larger, I get the error:

```
POST http://localhost:53319/customers/116/fileupload/Production 404 (Not Found)
Failed to load http://localhost:53319/customers/116/fileupload/Production: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 404.
```

For my case, I need to be able to upload files of up to 10 Gbs. Does anyone know why I get this error for files of larger than a  certain size and how I can fix it?

I've done some research into this already, and all I've found is to add the following to the Web.config file, but hasn't solved the issue.

```
<system.web>
  <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2147483647" />
</system.web>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this kind of web.config or at least that requestLimits part. This is from .Net Core project so syntax may vary.

https://github.com/JanneHarju/MultiSourcePlayList/blob/cbbe3460d107cd07d01ee80e0693f905a295f392/web.config#L11

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <security>
        <requestFiltering>
            <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="524288000"/>
        </requestFiltering>
    </security>
    <handlers>
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified"/>
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore processPath="%LAUNCHER_PATH%" arguments="%LAUNCHER_ARGS%" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" forwardWindowsAuthToken="false"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Here is some documentation about it https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/security/requestfiltering/requestlimits/

> The default value is 30000000, which is approximately 28.6MB.

Comment: All I needed was the `<requestFiltering>` section. Thank you! For any others who run into this issue, `maxAllowedContentLength` is of type `uint` which has a max value of 4294967295. That means, in my case for example, the file upload maximum is going to be ~4.29 GB.